# ¿Cómo Elevar a la Potencia con Reales Sin Bucles y Sin el Método Math.Pow?

Tags: vb.net, math

Mi Pregunta es la Siguiente: ¿Cómo Puedo Elevar a Una Potencia Real Sin Utilizar el Método de Math.Pow?.

Mi Método Para Hacer esto es el Siguiente:

```
        Dim NumLogaritmo As Double = Math.Log(Num1)

        Dim NumResultado As Double = Num2 * NumLogaritmo
          
        Dim Resultado As Double = Math.Pow(CDbl(ConstanteE),CDbl(NumResultado))

        Return Resultado
```

El Método  funciona pero tendría  que  poder hacer-lo funcionar solo con sumas, restas, multiplicaciones, divisiones y raíces cuadradas que  es lo que tengo desarrollado hasta ahora .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo He Resuelto haciendo dos bucles con enteros y sacando su proporcionalidad, con el siguiente método:

```
    Dim Tempo1 As String = Num1
    Dim Man As Integer = Cero
    Dim Resultado1 As String = Num1
    Dim Resultado2 As String = Num1
    Dim NumElevations As Integer = Cero

    If BigNumbers.IsReal(Num2) = True Then

        NumElevations = CInt(PolStrings.StringsLeft(Num2))

        For Man = Uno To NumElevations - Uno Step Uno
            Resultado1 = PolStrings.StringsFormatCeros(BigNumbers.Multiplicar(Tempo1, Resultado1))
        Next

        NumElevations = CInt(PolStrings.StringsLeft(Num2)) + Uno

        For Man = Uno To NumElevations - Uno Step Uno
            Resultado2 = PolStrings.StringsFormatCeros(BigNumbers.Multiplicar(Tempo1, Resultado2))
        Next

        Dim Restados As String = BigNumbers.Restar(Resultado2, Resultado1)

        Dim Base10 As String = PolStrings.StringsToCerosToRight(StringUno, Len(PolStrings.StringsRight(Num2)))

        Dim ResultadoDivision As String = BigNumbers.Divide(Restados, Base10, Reiterations)

        Return BigNumbers.Sumar(Resultado1, BigNumbers.Multiplicar(ResultadoDivision, BigNumbers.Divide(PolStrings.StringsRight(Num2), Base10 & StringCero, Reiterations)))

    Else

        NumElevations = CInt(Num2)

        For Man = Uno To NumElevations - Uno Step Uno
            Resultado1 = PolStrings.StringsFormatCeros(BigNumbers.Multiplicar(Tempo1, Resultado1))
        Next

        Return Resultado1
    End If
```